# Seaborn, how to draw 2 lines from same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
client = CosmosClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY)
database = client.get_database_client(database=DATABASE_ID)
container = database.get_container_client(CONTAINER_ID)

item_list = list(container.read_all_items(max_item_count=10))
df = pd.DataFrame(item_list)
```

and it returns a DF like this:

```
       eui   BatV  TempC_DS  TempC_SHT  \
0     A8404181D1822E6B  2.985     16.25      16.03   
1     A84041A3A1822FE5  2.982      7.06      16.28   
2     A8404181D1822E6B  2.985     16.31      16.09   
3     A84041A3A1822FE5  2.982      7.93      16.43   
4     A8404181D1822E6B  2.983     16.50      16.20   
...                ...    ...       ...        ...   
1815  A84041A3A1822FE5  2.998      9.75      19.84   
1816  A8404181D1822E6B  3.010     23.43      23.86   
1817  A8404181D1822E6B  3.010     23.37      23.82   
1818  A84041A3A1822FE5  2.996      9.50      19.82   
1819  A8404181D1822E6B  3.012     23.43      23.81   

              EventEnqueuedUtcTime                                    id  \
0     2021-02-02T08:05:47.1660000Z  5f185a0d-5000-4831-889c-a48c431ca894   
1     2021-02-02T08:21:57.9240000Z  41c21f2f-0160-464c-901c-24c0a1119dc0   
2     2021-02-02T08:25:47.8710000Z  9781d546-56ab-4ccb-b7dd-de4415a949c4   
3     2021-02-02T08:41:57.4140000Z  de3e9ea0-3752-4cef-9056-554b66c83447   
4     2021-02-02T08:45:47.8500000Z  a3436591-eb8e-4705-9aeb-a43684d560f3   
...                            ...                                   ...   
1815  2021-02-18T14:42:26.1720000Z  1f9fb3a6-d17b-43ab-b296-31f58acff0f7   
1816  2021-02-18T14:45:42.3140000Z  8b3ae737-65f3-42ba-af6c-bb680ddbd42e   
1817  2021-02-18T15:05:51.8630000Z  71947375-f5a4-44c8-9462-88d77ac2eb9e   
1818  2021-02-18T15:22:19.7500000Z  2009b9cd-dce5-4408-a50b-f70446d30461   
1819  2021-02-18T15:25:40.7930000Z  85e9f24b-8c69-42c4-b017-aa81e0170524
```

I want to create a line chart with 2 lines (one for each sensor EUI/field) which shows the temperature in the Y axis and X would be the event queue time.

I tried this:

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Convert to type float
index_df = df.loc[:,('TempC_DS','EventEnqueuedUtcTime')].astype('float')

# Create the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
# Set a Seaborn chart style
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
# Plot three Seaborn line charts
line1 = sns.lineplot(x='EventEnqueuedUtcTime',y='TempC_DS',data=index_df, label='Inside')
line2 = sns.lineplot(x='EventEnqueuedUtcTime',y='TempC_DS',data=index_df,label='Outside')


plt.ylabel('Temp')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.title('Temp over time, Inside Vs Outside')
plt.savefig('Temperature ')
```

But I have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9ed9fad92eff> in <module>
      3 
      4 # Convert to type float
----> 5 index_df = df.loc[:,('TempC_DS','EventEnqueuedUtcTime')].astype('float')
      6 
      7 # Create the figure
```

Comment: Use list instead of tuple: `['TempC_DS','EventEnqueuedUtcTime']`?

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: Just remove `index_df` altogether and replace `data=index_df` by `data=df` in the `lineplot` commands.

Comment: stil the same error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2021-02-02T08:05:47.1660000Z'

Comment: Yes, you cant convert that string to float. do `df['Event...'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event...'])` first.

Comment: ok good, please note that the eui column has 2 devices, I need a LINE per device, and its only drawing one line

Comment: pass `hue='eui'` and keep just one `lineplot` command.

Comment: amazing!, finally, without filtering the pandas dataframe, is there an easy way to plot only for example last day? last week? last 12 hours?